# Play the sound going through my speakers through my mic?

Tags: windows-8.1

I want to play all the sound that is going through my speakers into my mic. What I do now is I just put the mic right up to the speakers so it captures the sound, but that's annoying because the quality isn't very good. Is there a better way?

Comment: a better way for what? what is the purpose of you doing this exactly?

Comment: We need your operating system at a minimum.

Comment: @Xavierjazz Windows 8.1, it's in the tag.

Comment: A. What are you really attempting to do? You might not be going about solving it in the best manner by what you've described. B. Is this an attempt to record what's being played through the speakers? Get a sound program like **Audacity** and directly record the output stream. C. Are you attempting to play the computer sound while combining it with other sound the Mic picks up? You need a sound mixing board that matches the speaker out impedance to the mic in impedance and mixes it with other sound input to be input into the speaker jack.

Comment: @FiascoLabs A. Play a song through my mic B. No I want to play sound that is going through my speakers as my input for my mic C. No, just the sound the computer plays

Comment: There is a built in audio output recording source. Look in the volume manager under recording. This is at least true the last time I checked.

Comment: I don't see it ([image](http://puu.sh/6zBuo.png))

Comment: @chipperyman573, I just can't see the logic in using a sound input device such as the mic as an output. In your setup describe above, where's your mic plugged in? Is it connected to something like an amplifier?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run line-out output directly into Mic input (no mic used) you will get the best sound by using a resistor divider to match line-out impedance (100Ω) to Mic input impedance (10kΩ). Covered over here on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/60949/connect-speaker-output-to-microphone-input

Line-out (green) can be plugged directly to Line-In (blue) without any extra circuitry.